# How to check whether a text box just accepts numbers using selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm new using selenium web driver and I want to validate if a textbox only accepts numbers so I want to validate that if I send a text, the textbox would not allow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do something like:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Class("textbox")).SendKeys("euiwt8947");
string text=driver.FindElement(By.Class("textbox")).Text;
bool isNumeric =  text.All(char.IsDigit);
```

Steps:

1- Send Keys to textbox.

2- Get text from textbox.

3- Check if the text you got is only numeric.

Or if a textbox allows you to input text then validation message will appear, just check that an error message has appeared.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in a number of ways.

1. You could fill in the field using `sendkeys()`, wait for any validation popup to be displayed. If the validation popup is displayed, the test passes. If not the test fails.
2. You could fill in all the necessary fields, click next and then wait and see if the application returns any error. If the error is displayed the test passes, if not it fails.

Comment: that would not work for textboxes which will not allow user to input text from the first place.